# SAS proc format for background colours for dates including blank values

Tags: sas

I have this code where I create a proc format statement for dates based on todays date.
Any date prior to today is red and any date in the future is green.  However this is a proc report I am calling this statement in and there are blank values for date in some cases.  Therefore, I want fields that don't contain a date to be white.

```
data _null_;
sdate = date ();
format sdate date9.;
call symput('sdate',sdate);
run;

proc format;
  value closefmt 
    low - &sdate ='red'
    ' ' = 'white'
    &sdate - high = 'green';

run;
```

It doesn't like ' ' = white and doesn't accept null.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use single dot for missing values in numeric variable:

```
proc format;
  value closefmt 
    low - &sdate ='red'
    . = 'white'
    &sdate - high = 'green';

run;

/* test code */
data indata;
    d = .; output;
    do i=-3 to 3;
       d = today()+i;
       output;
    end;
run;

data _null_;
    set indata;
    format d yymmdds10.;
    length color $10;
    color = put(d, closefmt. - L);
    putlog d color;
run;
```